# `rvm list remote` not showing binaries for Ubuntu 14.04 box

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to provision a dev box with rvm on Ubuntu 14.04 (via Vagrant and Ansible). I've installed rvm:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

When I try to `rvm install 1.9.3` or `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551 it says that no binaries can be found, and it'll compile from source.

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
```

There *are* binaries available, though: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/config/remote & https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/

Doing `rvm --debug list remote` yields:

```
__list_remote_all https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries ubuntu/14.04/x86_64
__list_remote_all1 https://s3.amazonaws.com/jruby.org downloads
__list_remote_for_s3-0 https://s3.amazonaws.com/jruby.org?prefix=downloads/
Running(15): curl --fail --location --max-redirs 10 --max-time 1800 --connect-timeout 30 --retry-delay 2 --retry 3 -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/jruby.org?prefix=downloads/
__list_remote_for_s3-1 https://s3.amazonaws.com/jruby.org?prefix=downloads/&marker=downloads/1.6.5/jruby-bin-1.6.5.tar.gz.sha1
Running(15): curl --fail --location --max-redirs 10 --max-time 1800 --connect-timeout 30 --retry-delay 2 --retry 3 -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/jruby.org?prefix=downloads/&marker=downloads/1.6.5/jruby-bin-1.6.5.tar.gz.sha1
__list_remote_all2 http://binaries.rubini.us ubuntu/14.04/x86_64
__list_remote_for_s3-0 http://binaries.rubini.us?prefix=ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/
Running(15): curl --fail --location --max-redirs 10 --max-time 1800 --connect-timeout 30 --retry-delay 2 --retry 3 -s http://binaries.rubini.us?prefix=ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/
__list_remote_all3 https://rubies.travis-ci.org ubuntu/14.04/x86_64

# Remote rubies available:

jruby-0.9.0
jruby-1.6.6
jruby-1.6.7
jruby-1.6.7.2
jruby-1.6.8
jruby-1.7.0
jruby-1.7.0.preview1
jruby-1.7.0.preview2
jruby-1.7.0.RC1
jruby-1.7.0.RC2
jruby-1.7.1
jruby-1.7.10
jruby-1.7.11
jruby-1.7.12
jruby-1.7.13
jruby-1.7.14
jruby-1.7.15
jruby-1.7.16
jruby-1.7.16.1
jruby-1.7.2
jruby-1.7.3
jruby-1.7.4
jruby-1.7.5
jruby-1.7.6
jruby-1.7.7
jruby-1.7.8
jruby-1.7.9
rubinius-2.3.0

# * - installed already

# To download and install: rvm install {name} --binary

__rvm_rm_rf already gone: /home/vagrant/.rvm/tmp/18526*
```

Using `rvm mount` does work, but I'd like to avoid that as I'm trying to keep this vagrant box as generic as possible.

```
$ rvm mount -r https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.tar.bz2
https://rvm.io/binaries/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.tar.bz2 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #download
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13.3M  100 13.3M    0     0   343k      0  0:00:39  0:00:39 --:--:--  350k
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #validate archive
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #validate binary
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #setup
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #gemset created /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #importing gemset         /home/vagrant/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems....................................
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #gemset created /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #importing gemsetfile /home/vagrant/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #generating default wrappers......
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm sure I *am* doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a problem with RVM itself. https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3180